# Kubernetes stuck on port forwarding the nginx-pod 8080:80

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, portforwarding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZkr9.png)

It is not not forwarding to the web browser , Nothing is happening after showing
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80

Comment: Its not stuck.  When port forwarding is enabled for a pod it will forwards the request from localport to port on the pod.  When you stop the port forwarding then it will stop listening.  You can refer official document on the same https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Comment: Hey Nataraj, in hindsight, I think your comment is just right for the answer, would u like to put it as answer and me to remove mine?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what Nataraj Medayhal mention.

It is not that "nothing is happening". It is awaiting for a response. In addition to Nataraj link, I think this is another good example

it uses an example here for port forward to redis
https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-port-forward/
[image: pic of app]